# junit test for java:comp/env

Tags: junit, jndi

my server side has a method with code like following

```
Context ctx = (Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
```

how to test this method in client using JUnit or even a standalone application?
I try to do the following but still fail

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
        try {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
                "org.apache.naming");            
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

            // Construct DataSource
            OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
            ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db");
            ds.setUser("MY_USER_NAME");
            ds.setPassword("MY_USER_PASSWORD");

            ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/nameofmyjdbcresource", ds);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyDAOTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

the exception is
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:remaining name:env

in fact, I think in server, once new InitialContext(), all the previous create subcontext in client is clear, is it?